# flutter released apk installed but not opening

Tags: flutter-release

their have been a problem with my flutter app that i released, it works when i run it on my device and also works on emulators before release but after i sign the app and release it it stop working when i open it it crashes and close itself automatically any answer can help

check my code on github
https://github.com/oriemiobang/Dha-Anywaa-application

thank you for your time

i tried everything i read on stackoverflow here but still nothing works
i tried giving it internet access even if the app doesn't need internet